# Using custom data holder in Django

Tags: django, model

I am working Django for last few days with a legacy database. I have a following scenario to handle as I need to expose a API giving out values :

- I have a data holder ( say a python class - with attributes : name , value and date fields ) which gets populated by a Custom Data Procedure , so its not like one to one mapped with Data Table in database
  -So the question is how to make make this data holder compatible with Django -In short how to call dataHolder.objects.all() , dataholder.obhects.get , and other such queries...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You're basically talking about reimplementing the ORM. That's a pretty massive task, probably not what you want to do. What's the underlying goal - IOW, why do you want a django.db.models.Model API?

Comment: @AdamKG: Thanks for the reply. I have one underlying table having 3 columns - Name,Date and Array of Comma Separated Values in the table. Logically in the program the table row is a list of Python Objects , having attribute as Name , Date and each of the array value. I need to expose this as json list to external users.